Difference between fact-check and cross-check in American English?
According to Merriam-Webster's dictionary, the definitions of the two words are the following:

cross-check ... 2 : to check (something, such as data or reports) from various angles or sources to determine validity or accuracy


fact-check : to verify the factual accuracy of

What confuses me is that fact-checking and cross-checking both involve comparing information from a source resource to another resource, so there is a lot of overlap between the two and this confuses me.
Also, when cross-checking a piece of information, how many additional sources should be used in addition the the original source whose information we are trying to verify, so that the activity can count as cross-checking?
I'd really appreciate it if you could demystify the difference between these two words. I have consulted a bunch of dictionaries but all in vain.
Thank you in advance.

It's literally right in the words you quote. Cross-check implies checking from various angles or sources, i.e. different approaches/directions/methods/people. What don't you understand about the words you quote?

@StuartF If the OP has a hard time seeing the difference, telling them it's obvious doesn't lead them to an answer. If they knew what they didn't understand, they'd probably know how to answer, and they probably wouldn't be asking here. Anyway, the answer is not in the words quoted.

This has zero to do with AmE. It's just English.

@Mitch Thank you for being so good and honest. [chuckles]

You can probably use the two phrases interchangeably in many cases.
Cross checking is more associated with comparing two or more sets of data looking for agreement and discrepancies. Such as the results of the same experiment run by two different researchers or a detective cross checking witness statements to see if they agree or contradict each other. No one set of data is guaranteed 100% accurate.
Fact checking is often associated with news or claims by others. So, for example, if a politician says "I had 100,000 people attend my rally", someone fact checking might go to independent sources (such as aerial photographs) to verify that claim. Or a News channel might say that they couldn't fact check a death toll for some disaster as there was no data. In these cases the facts are expected to be truthful and 100% verifiable.

(Boiled down: "fact check" is less appropriate when the sources being checked are all "fact-based," i.e. objective data, but may or may not be accurate or accurately processed. "Fact check" is most appropriate where there's some concern that the source may not be based in actual fact at all.)

@Peter Jennings. Thank you. So cross checking isn't about establishing whether a fact is correct or not but it's about seeing if there are any differences between reports, witness statements, etc. Whereas fact checking is about verifying the veracity of a claim, piece of information, etc. Have I understood your answer correctly?

@ldk29 not a "fact" but an assertion, a statement. A fact is always factual. Is what was said factual?  And cross-checking does not check for "veracity" but for corroboration, not granting the one or the other any special truth status.  Fact-checking checks for veracity.  Cross-checking relies on corroboration of one or more records but does not extend to determining whether any of them is factual.

Agree there's a lot of overlap, but I might say "cross check" is a bit more broad - a fact check will usually involve cross checking against other sources, but a cross check might not involve a fact check. For example, airplane crew or maintenance workers commonly cross check others' work to make sure everything is done properly, but I wouldn't call it a "fact check". The purpose of a fact check is usually just to say whether something is correct or not, but the purpose of a cross check is often to verify that something is in fact correct before proceeding to another step.

They serve a different purpose entirely.
Cross Check – there are at least 2 sources which have been compiled separately, such as a record of bookkeeping that needs to tally with receipts for financial accounting.
There is no assumption of fraud or malfeasance. Cross check is a safety feature designed to catch mathematical errors and procedural inconsistencies. Two different medical studies could be cross-checked for example, it doesn't mean one was wrong.
It is not a full audit of the 'the truth'. Both records are assumed to be made in good faith so the 2 sources just need to agree. If not, some action is taken (recheck the math for starters).
Fact Check – verifying the objective truth of someone's statement. There is an assumption the statement is at least partially false, is manipulative, or intentionally obscures the truth through omission.
Fact Check comes from news media, it's their assumed responsibility to hold powerful people accountable for their false claims. However, it uses a language trick of shifting blame away from the person who said it, thus not directly calling them a liar. It is 'the facts' that are checked, and 'the facts' that are corrected.

Hehe, I know of at least one scientific study near me in which there was some malfeasance (faking the results), which could well be a good reason for cross-checking. Also: while there may be a euphemistic overtone to "fact check" lately, it's not just for powerful people; if the paper reports on Old Man Hopkin's house fire, and Hopkins says he thinks it was arson and his neighbor started it, the paper is obliged to investigate.

It should be added that one role of fact in the phrase fact checking is to make it clear that the process is concerned only with the factual content of what someone has said; it is not concerned with its rhetorical aspects. The first step in fact checking is thus often to separate the factual claims that can be subject to fact checking from the spin that may have been superimposed on them.

Premise: The cow jumped over the moon."
We can cross check many reports to verify this happened. However, to fact check it, we would have to find witnesses, study if this is even possible, and most importantly,  understand the context of the statement.
