Difference between cross referencing and cross checking in American English
I thought that this qualified as cross-checking:
A detective asks two witnesses questions and then cross-checks their answers to see whether there are any striking differences between the two. It's not about finding out whether the two witnesses told them the truth. It's about seeing if there are things that don't match. I assume the purpose of this is to give the detective a broad overview of the missing puzzle pieces.
Let's say each witnesses states that the suspicious man had many similar descriptive features but then they state different beard colors. With this discrepancy, the detective knows that they only need to find out which color the man's beard actually was in order to get closer to finding the suspect.
But it turned out that this was cross-referencing.
I am really confused because cross-checking means comparing two or more things to look for discrepancies but this seems to be the case with cross-referencing too. Do the following actions count as cross checking or cross-referencing and why?

A student compares their essay to the sample essay to see if they covered all the important points or not.
Two translators compare their translations of the same text to see if there is anything in one translation that doesn't line up with the other.


You've asked a lot of questions about cross checking etc, but there isn't a simple difference. Some people will call a thing cross-checking, others will call it cross-referencing. In some organizations there are procedures with defined names; in other organizations (like maybe the police) there are particular usages that are traditional. But in general, I wouldn't worry about the difference.

Thank you. So what you're basically saying is that even native speakers use these two interchangeably?

I think Stuart just said the opposite in some ways: Some contexts pick one or the other, but there isn't universal agreement from one context to another. "Cross-checking" is just not a terribly common compound.

To me, cross referencing means identifying related items in two collections of information. For instance, in computer programming a cross reference will list all the places that call a function or refer to a variable.

OTOH, cross checking means checking for consistency between related items.

This is similar to the question you asked here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/626381/difference-between-fact-check-and-cross-check-in-american-english/626384#626384

I am a native American English speaker, and there is no difference to me. I use them interchangeably. If there actually is a difference, I'm not aware of it at all. Great question.

The adverb "cross" is irrelevant. The difference is between the verbs to check and to reference. Both are in dictionaries.

The adverb "cross" is irrelevant. The difference is between the verbs to check and to reference. Both are in dictionaries.
